# copy filtered value and paste to different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have code below help me to copy filtered value and paste to different worksheet.
It always stop at apple... (Apple result looks fine)and pop up Run-time error'1004' Application-defined or object-defined error..

```
Sub CoWFTR()

'Filter out Apple
    Sheet1.Range("A1:ER1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "ILOVEApple"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

'Copy and Paste to Apple Tab
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Apple").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Clear Filter
On Error Resume Next
    Sheet1.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0

'Filter out Banana
    Sheet1.Range("A1:ER1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "ILOVEBanana"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

'Copy and Paste to Banana Tab
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Banana").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste


Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Clear Filter
On Error Resume Next
    Sheet1.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: I highly recommend learning how to compound your code to get rid of `Select`. For instance: `Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select` and `Selection.Copy` can become just `Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Copy`

Comment: To address your issue though I think the problem is you're just selecting the worksheet ("Apple") but not specifying a range to paste the copied info in? Will it work with `Sheets("Apple").Range("A1").Select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the 2 procedures bellow in the same module, and update **FILTER_ITEMS** with your criteria:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CoWFTR()
    Const FILTER_COL    As Long = 11    'K
    Const FILTER_ITEMS  As String = "ILOVEApple,ILOVEBanana"
    Dim wsFrom As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, fi As Variant, i As Long

    Set wsFrom = Sheet1 '<--- Update this

    fi = Split(FILTER_ITEMS, ",")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 0 To UBound(fi)
        Set wsDest = CheckNamedSheet(fi(i))
        With wsFrom.UsedRange
            .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="=" & fi(i), Operator:=xlFilterValues
            .Copy   'Copy visible data
        End With
        With wsDest.Cells
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            wsDest.Activate
            .Cells(1, 1).Select
        End With
    Next
    With wsFrom
        .Activate
        .Cells(1, 1).Copy
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

This manages the new sheets

```
Private Function CheckNamedSheet(ByVal sheetName As String) As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet, result As Boolean, activeWS As Worksheet

    Set activeWS = IIf(ActiveSheet.Name = sheetName, Worksheets(1), ActiveSheet)
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name = sheetName Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ws.Delete   'delete sheet if it already exists
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))    'create a new one
    ws.Name = sheetName
    activeWS.Activate
    Set CheckNamedSheet = ws
End Function
```

---

For your code, the error you are getting is at this line:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
```

It repeats for Bananas as well, and is triggered by the fact that it tries to select Range("A1") on Sheet1, but the active sheet is Apple (or Banana), so to fix the issues you need to add this line:

```
Sheet1.Activate
```

Here is your code, fixed:

```
Sub CoWFTR()

'Filter out Apple
    Sheet1.Range("A1:ER1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "ILOVEApple"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

'Copy and Paste to Apple Tab
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Apple").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheet1.Activate          'Fix to error 1004
Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Clear Filter
On Error Resume Next
    Sheet1.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0

'Filter out Banana
    Sheet1.Range("A1:ER1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "ILOVEBanana"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

'Copy and Paste to Banana Tab
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Banana").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheet1.Activate          'Fix to error 1004
Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Clear Filter
On Error Resume Next
    Sheet1.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I think it is useful using xlCellTypeVisible. And Use Array.

```
Sub CoWFTR()
Dim WS As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
Dim rngDB As Range, rngTo As Range
Dim vCriteria, vName, i As Integer

    Set WS = Sheet1
    Set toWs = Sheets("Apple")
    Set rngDB = WS.Range("a1").CurrentRegion

    vCriteria = Array("ILOVEApple", "ILOVEBanana")
    vName = Array("Apple", "Banana")

    For i = 0 To UBound(vCriteria)
        If WS.FilterMode Then
            WS.ShowAllData
        End If
        Set toWs = Sheets(vName(i))
        Set rngTo = toWs.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)

        rngDB.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=Array( _
        vCriteria(i)), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        rngDB.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(1).Copy rngTo

    Next i

    If WS.FilterMode Then
        WS.ShowAllData
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting, If I want only "I love apple" in apple tab and " I love banana" in banana tab, how to reach it with your code?

Comment: @SpringBunny: vName = Array("Apple", "Banana")  ~~>Set toWs = Sheets(vName(i))
    ////  vCriteria = Array("ILOVEApple", "ILOVEBanana") ~~> Criteria1:=Array( _
        vCriteria(i)),